# How do I override rails route helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to override rails route helper methods so that they handle model instances differently? I just finished creating a `User` model that does not inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, but instead uses methods that I wrote to retrieve users from an LDAP database. However, now all the route helper methods are messed up. (For example, `user_path(user)` gives `/users/#<User:0x3df82a0>` instead of `/users/002131`)

I tried overriding the method with the following code (placed inside of the `User` model) but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any ideas?

```
class << Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  def user_path(user)
    if user.class == User
      users_path + "/#{user.id}"
    else
      users_path + "/#{user}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a `to_param` method on your model and when you pass that to a route helper it should call that method.

An example: most of the time you route by a Model ID, so a call like

```
user_path(some_user)
```

generates a URL like `/users/45`

But lets say you have a unique username that you want to use in the route, so you would just do:

```
class User
  def to_param
    username
  end
end
```

Then a call to `user_path(user)` would generate something like: `/users/blackbear`

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping there might be a way to do something like that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would you happen to know if there is a way to do something similar with the link_to helper methods? Those don't seem to be affected by to_param. I can, of course, set them to point to `user_path(user)` instead of just `user`, but it would be nice if there was a simple way to just make link_to work normally.